# Problems loading image from json / why is my bitmap null?

Tags: android, json, bitmap, android-asynctask, bitmapimage

I've been trying to understand why my bitmap is null, but I couldn't do it so far. This is what I have in my Model:

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String imageURL) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        URL urlImage = new URL(imageURL);
        httpRequest = new HttpGet(urlImage.toURI());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And this is what I have in my `onPostExecute` of my `AsyncTask`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            position = extras.getString("position");
            int positionInt = Integer.parseInt(position);

            String price = "";
            String description = "";
            String image = "";

            try {
                JSONObject ad = json.getJSONObject(positionInt);
                price = ad.getString("price");
                description = ad.getString("description");
                image = ad.getString("image");
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            TextView viewPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view_price);
            viewPrice.setText(price);

            TextView viewDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view_description);
            viewDescription.setText(description);

            final String imageURL = "http://192.168.0.16:3000" + image;

            Bitmap bitmap = jParser.getBitmapFromUrl(imageURL);
            System.out.println(bitmap);
            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view_photo_image);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            super.onPostExecute(json);

        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Have you observed any logs? Have You tried same URL from browser?

Comment: yes, same url works just fine on browser. i couldn't figure out. i was trying to let the image request in my model like i've shown above, but i gave up and put it in my activity. it's not what i wanted but it worked.